# Very simple onclick not working

Tags: javascript, html

I can't get this onclick event to work. It is working fine in the code snippet here but not at all in my asp.net project. As in the event is simply not firing.

The only difference from the example posted here, is that the script is in an external JS file - it's  definitely being loaded okay though (as other stuff from it is working such as my onLoad).

I have just tried to call an in-line alert rather than function on the onclick event and that works fine. So something is preventing me from calling an function in the JS file.

I have also tried to remove the javascript: prefix to no avail.

```js
/*
Sample of my script
*/

var project = "Blah"  // URL project
var divReportList = "#divHRFAccord"
var divReportTarget = "#rightPanel"

function FolderClick(folderID, treePath) {
// Reload right frame
alert("Hello");
}

$(document).ready(function () {
// Load folders
LoadFolders(divReportList);
});

// Load folder accordion 
function LoadFolders() {
};

function LoadFolderhtml(dta) {
}
```

```css
/* Misc */
.mrHand {
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="~/Scripts/myScript.js"></script>

<a style="color:black" class="mrHand" onclick="javascript:FolderClick('1','2')">Clickable Text</a>
```

Comment: Everything's working

Comment: Is the definition of `FolderClick` inside another function perhaps?

Comment: @Pointy - Nope, it's just a regular function sat near the top of the script. I'm starting to thing there's something wrong with the configuration of javascript on this site in general (it's not my site) because I also can't get bootstrap to collapse/expand an accordion (which uses bootstrap JS).

Comment: Well there's no "configuration of JavaScript" server-side, other than to have the files in the right place. If the files aren't being loaded, then of course they won't work, but if you're sure they *are* being loaded then there's nothing that any normal server needs to do.

Comment: Try removing the `javascript:` prefix from the onclick="" attribute. It is not needed in that context (only in href="") and could be the source of the problem depending on the browser.

Comment: @Pointy yeah I've never come across this on my own sites. Can't work it out at all. Both onclick and data-toggle events are not being fired. Mouse click is effectively being ignored.

Comment: @musicfuel I have tried that, I should have said. Sorry. Also doesn't work.. will leave it out though as it's tidier if it isn't needed.

Comment: Since this is on larger site, is it possible that some other element is overlaying your <a> tag and basically trapping the clicks? Does your <a> tag respond to hover with CSS?

Comment: @musicfuel or you can try this wonderful bookmarklet to test this: http://sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2

Comment: @musicfuel I've just placed a simple html button at the top of the page <button type="button" onclick="FolderClick('1','2')">Clickable Text</button> and the event is still being ignored..

Comment: ... and there are no errors in the browser console?

Comment: @Pointy Correct, no errors.

Comment: So.. the click event is working ok if I don't call the function and just do an in-line alert. Has to be related to it being external, somehow.

Comment: Please update the answer with the <script> tag you are using to include the script. Also, if you can provide any of the script in that file to show how `FolderClick()` is defined within it that may be helpful.

Comment: @musicfuel Script added with sensitive parts removed. Script tag added. Script is definitely working.. document ready works perfectly and does the stuff it's meant to do.

Comment: And the FolderClick() is *not* inside the document.ready handler? What happens if you type `window.FolderClick` in the browser console?

Comment: @Pointy yeah I've updated the post to show the exact layout. Trying it in console gives an "undefined" so somethings definitely up.

Comment: Never mind guys, facepalm time. Had the function defined twice (one wayyy down at the bottom and with no code inside and one parameter) - I guess this caused it to go haywire.

Comment: If it's `undefined` when you type that then clicking the `<a>` element should produce an `undefined is not a function` error in the console too. In any case, that means that even though your script is loading, the function isn't ending up being defined as a global function. The most likely causes would be a syntax error somewhere in the script, or else that the function is defined inside something like a "ready" or "load" handler function.

Comment: @Pointy it was me being a dullard. I did however learn about the console from your comments, which is brilliant. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a duplicate definition of the function `FolderClick` in the script.